# !preg_match returning invalid email address error

Tags: php, validation, email, preg-match

I have used following code to ensure email address provided on signup are valid.

```
if (!preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
    $msg = $msg."Email Id Not Valid, Please Enter The Correct Email Id .<BR>";
    $status = "NOTOK";
}
```

I entered a standard email `myemail@gmail.com` but it's flagging it as invalid.

Please help me why it is flagging it.

Comment: Why do you put `!` at the beginning ?

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not be using a regular expression for this when there is built in validation:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $msg.="Email Id Not Valid, Please Enter The Correct Email Id ."; 
    $status= "NOTOK";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i", $email)) 
{  
   $emailErr = "Email Id Not Valid, Please Enter The Correct Email Id";
}
```

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if(isset($_POST["email"]))
{
        $emaill = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
  // $reg = '/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/';
    if(!preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/",$emaill))
        {
            die('<i class="fa fa-times red"></i> Enter valid email!!!');

        }
        else{
             die('<i class="fa fa-check green"></i> Valid!!!');

        }
}
```

Comment: there is a lot wrong with this regular expression such as domains that end with more than 4  letters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html